# Please Tell me the Name of this type of view described in attached Image

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I want to make a popup window same as in attached snapshoot. I dont Know what we call this type of view so I am asking here. Plz tell me The Name of this type of view. Or Point me to the Right Direction. any tutorial link will be help full.[image]

Comment: You make a div, with relative position, and you open it and close it (show/hide)

Comment: There are a tonne of different ways to do something like this. There are probably several JS add-ons out there that do this too.

With ASP.NET, you can use AJAX Hover Panel extenders as well.

But using divs with show/hide is probably best. Keep it simple

Comment: Thanks For your reply. I will try the provided links in the ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is nothing but a div which has been shown at some ( x , y ) position , what you need to do is to inspect this associated popup div and you will find that, it is just a div with some css applied on it ( believe me it is nothing more than that and could be easily accomplished ) , just the thing is to make a div and initially make it hidden , and on some click pick your div from its id and make it visible and that's it. Same has been shown here :

1. http://www.pat-burt.com/csspopup.html#
2. http://istockphp.com/demo/popup-div-with-jquery/ ( a bit more fancy )

Thanks

Comment: ok. let me try these . thanks. will ask you if need assistance :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to apply animation like ease out , so it cant show up suddenly ?

Comment: Yes you can apply fade-in effect ( will be most appropriate for this I believe) like this : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein

Comment: Thanks Usman. Thats all i need. :) going to accept this as ANS :)